# How to get a member of the structure if offset is known?

Tags: c, pointers

So, I have a structure

```
struct foo
{
  int a;
  int b;
  int c;
  char *string;
};
typedef struct foo foo;
```

And I have a function

```
void fun(void *data1, void *data2, int offset){
  int num1 = *(int *)(data1 + offset);
  int num2 = *(int *)(data2 + offset);
  printf("%d %d\n", num1, num2);
}
```

And it works great. But Something is wrong when I try to do the same with strings.

```
void fun(void *data1, void *data2, int offset){
  char *str1 = (char *)(data1 + offset);
  char *str2 = (char *)(data2 + offset);
  printf("%s %s\n", str1, str2);
}
```

Function just prints some random characters. I am starting to get a headache because of pointers...

Comment: How are you calling `fun()`?

Comment: Doing arithmetic with `void` pointers is an extension.

Comment: By the way, you could have sorted this out yourself if you printed the base address of your `foo` instances along with the offset and then had the `fun` function print the address it was trying to access (hint: use `%p` to print pointers using `printf` and friends).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The address+offset of a `char *` is a *pointer-to*-`char *`, in other words it is a `char **` (like in your working part, the address+offset of an `int` is a *pointer-to*-`int`, i.e. it is an `int *`).

Thus the definition and aceess needs to have an extra indirection in the type, i.e. `char **`

```
char *str1 = *(char **)(data1 + offset);
```

Comment: You get to the underlying issue correctly. But what do you get when you add an `offset` to a `void *`? Who knows... it's undefined behavior and that's bad. It should look more like this: `char *str1 = *(char **)((unsigned char *)data1 + offset);`

Comment: That's a different story.  Since it works in his int-sample, I guess there is a C-extension somewhere that does that (and it wasn't part of his question so I don't want to confuse the poor guy even more).

Comment: True, but you should still point that out for him and explain how he can do this properly. For all you know this "C-extension" will work fine for `int` but cause his computer to explode on anything else. Sometimes an answer has to address more than just the question.

Comment: There was already a comment to the question pointing this out.  And now you did too :-)